# Java GUI Calculator calculation error

Tags: java, user-interface

I need some help about Java GUI calculator.

Code is working fine for first calculation when I try to add 5 + 2 it gave me answer 7.

But when I try to make another multiply, addition ,minus etc calculation it give me error. I cant add anything to founded answer.

I know the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

```
String.format("%1$,.2f", result);
```

This cause problem.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
double firstnumb;
double secnumb;
double result;
String operations;
String ans;

public Calculator() {
    initComponents();


    jTextField1.setText("");

}



private void operators () {         
    switch (operations) {

        case "+": 
            result=firstnumb+secnumb;
              ans=String.format("%1$,.2f", result);
        jTextField1.setText(ans);
        break;
        case "-":
            result=firstnumb-secnumb;
              ans=String.format("%1$,.2f", result);
        jTextField1.setText(ans);
        break;
        case "*":
            result=firstnumb*secnumb;
         ans=String.format("%1$,.2f", result);
        jTextField1.setText(ans);
        break;
        case "/":
            result=firstnumb/secnumb;
          ans=String.format("%1$,.2f", result);
        jTextField1.setText(ans);
        break;
        case "%":
            result=firstnumb%secnumb;
          ans=String.format("%1$,.2f", result);
        jTextField1.setText(ans);break;
        default: jTextField1.setText("");break;

    }

}

private void BtnMultiplyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   
{                                            
   firstnumb=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    jTextField1.setText("");

    operations="*";
       jTextField2.setText(firstnumb + operations);

}                                           

private void BtnCActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)       
{                                     
   jTextField1.setText("");
   jTextField2.setText("");
}                                    

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "1");

}                                        

private void jButton15ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
     jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "2");
}                                         

private void jButton16ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "3");
}                                         

private void jButton21ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "4");
}                                         

private void jButton22ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "5");
}                                         

private void jButton23ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "6");
}                                         

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "7");
}                                        

private void jButton12ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "8");
}                                         

private void jButton13ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "9");
}                                         

private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ "0");
}                                         

private void jButton19ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+ ".");
}                                         

private void BtnCEActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
     jTextField1.setText("");
     jTextField2.setText("");
}                                     

private void BtnEqualActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    secnumb=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());

        operators();


}                                        

private void BtnAdditionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    firstnumb=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    jTextField1.setText("");
    operations="+";
     jTextField2.setText(firstnumb + operations);
}                                           

private void BtnMinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     firstnumb=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    jTextField1.setText("");
    operations="-";
     jTextField2.setText(firstnumb + operations);
}                                        

private void BtnDivideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
      firstnumb=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    jTextField1.setText("");
    operations="/";
     jTextField2.setText(firstnumb + operations);
}                                         

private void BtnModActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
  firstnumb=Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    jTextField1.setText("");
    operations="%";
     jTextField2.setText(firstnumb + operations);
}                                      

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    double ops = Double.parseDouble (String.valueOf (jTextField1.getText()));
    ops=ops * (-1);
    jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(ops));

}
```

Comment: _it give me error_ whats the error?

Comment: ops. forgot to put error. http://tinypic.com/r/1441bip/9

Comment: Its a number format exception since you entered `14,00` its not a number.